# Node pool with VM with several vCPUs in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks

Suppose I have a node pool with a VM with 8 vCPUs. Can I specify in my yaml manifest which vCPU will execute the job? I do something similar in a node pool with several GPUs by specifying `containers`. I need to do the same for CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

You cant specify which CPU will do the job, nor can you specify which GPU will do the job. you can pin the pod to a node using nodeselectors, for example or just force pin it to the node.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: somepod
    namespace: default
spec:
    nodeName: node-name-goes-here
    containers:
    - image: something
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with I cannot specify which GPU will do the job. As I said, if I specify one container per GPU in my node, I can run different jobs in each GPU. I guess something similar should be possible to do with CPUs